# Qt programs errors with test

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlabel, qtwidgets

I'm trying to compile the dialog program from the qt book. I keep getting this error:

:'QLabel' : class has no constructors

pro:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    finddialog.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    finddialog.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

main:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "finddialog.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    FindDialog *dialog = new FindDialog;
    dialog->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Header:

```
#ifndef FINDDIALOG_H
#define FINDDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

class QCheckBox;
class QLabel;
class QLineEdit;
class QPushButton;
class QWidget;

class FindDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    FindDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
signals:
    void findNext(const QString &str, Qt::CaseSensitivity cs);
    void findPrevious(const QString &str, Qt::CaseSensitivity cs);
private slots:
    void findClicked();
    void enableFindButton(const QString &text);
private:
    QLabel *label;
    QLineEdit *lineEdit;
    QCheckBox *caseCheckBox;
    QCheckBox *backwardCheckBox;
    QPushButton *findButton;
    QPushButton *closeButton;
};

#endif // FINDDIALOG_H
```

Implement:

```
#include <QtGui>

#include "finddialog.h"

FindDialog::FindDialog(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
    label = new QLabel(tr("Find &what:"));
    lineEdit = new QLineEdit;
    label->setBuddy(lineEdit);

    caseCheckBox = new QCheckBox(tr("Match &case"));
    backwardCheckBox = new QCheckBox(tr("Search &backward"));

    findButton = new QPushButton(tr("&Find"));
    findButton->setDefault(true);
    findButton->setEnabled(false);

    closeButton = new QPushButton(tr("Close"));

    connect(lineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(enableFindButton(QString)));
    connect(findButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(findClicked()));
    connect(closeButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close()));

    QHBoxLayout *topLeftLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    topLeftLayout->addWidget(label);
    topLeftLayout->addWidget(lineEdit);

    QVBoxLayout *leftLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    leftLayout->addLayout(topLeftLayout);
    leftLayout->addWidget(caseCheckBox);
    leftLayout->addWidget(backwardCheckBox);

    QVBoxLayout *rightLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    rightLayout->addWidget(findButton);
    rightLayout->addWidget(closeButton);
    rightLayout->addStretch();

    QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addLayout(leftLayout);
    mainLayout->addLayout(rightLayout);
    setLayout(mainLayout);

    setWindowTitle(tr("Find"));
    setFixedHeight(sizeHint().height());
}

void FindDialog::findClicked()
{
    QString text = lineEdit->text();
    Qt::CaseSensitivity cs =
            caseCheckBox->isChecked() ? Qt::CaseSensitive
                : Qt::CaseInsensitive;
    if (backwardCheckBox->isChecked()) {
        emit findPrevious(text, cs);
    } else {
        emit findNext(text, cs);
    }
}

void FindDialog::enableFindButton(const QString &text)
{
    findButton->setEnabled(!text.isEmpty());
}
```

Comment: In which line are you getting that? Also, I do not see where your mainwindow would be used. Also, are you building with Qt 4 or Qt 5? The book was written for Qt 4, so if you are trying to build it against Qt 5, it will not work.

Comment: I think it should be `#include <QLabel>` instead of `class QLabel;`.

Comment: I'm using the exact same code from the book.

Comment: @System.exit: no, forward declaration is fine because it does not have to know the representation in the header.

Comment: I'm using qt version 5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> :'QLabel' : class has no constructors

It seems that you are including QtGui instead of QtWidgets. Replace this line:

```
#include <QtGui>
```

with

```
#include <QtWidgets>
```

if you are building with Qt 5. The book was written for Qt 4 and the widget classes moved into their own module.

Disclaimer: it is a bad idea to include the whole module.

Comment: #include <QtWidgets>   I replaced qtgui with qtwidgets C:\Users\x\Downloads\qt-book-examples\qt-book\chap02\find\finddialog.cpp:1: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtWidgets': No such file or directory

Comment: @runners3431: you have to install the widgets module, too. Make sure it is installed beside the other Qt dll files. Check also the header that it is available beside the similar headers. Check also the compiler line whether it has the correct include path passed on. I tested this on Linux before posting, and it worked for me.

Comment: i originally installed from the online installer. how do i install the module. using windows

Comment: That should have the widgets module installed, but double check it, and also whether the include path is passed to your compiler properly when building. If you are using qmake from the proper installation, it should just work.

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes when a program written in Qt 4 is compiled in Qt 5

The solution is:

1. Add following line in .pro file:

QT += core gui widgets

1. Include following header file:

> `#include <QtWidgets>`